# JTable reseting to original state after minimize/maximize

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I've got a Swing screen that opens with a JTable full of itenms and a JList that is empty. After an event from a button I *move* the itens from JTable to JList, making JTable empty and JList full of items as I desire. But I've got a weird problem that JTable goes back to its original state with all the items again when the frame is minimized and then maximized.

It should not happen as I remove the items from the array that keeps the JTable values. I used `sysout` to watch on console the array size as the items are being removed and I am sure in the end its size has come to zero.

Plus, I put break points in the `getXXX` that retrieves the array value to JTable and a `repaint()` method I put myself to overwrite its original and I got no break point pause of any of them.

So....I don't know where it is getting the value to reset to original state!

Finally, I've just noticed it happens when the table's area is clicked, so change the JFrame to a JDialog where there is no minimize/maximize button would not solve the problem at all.

I don't know if some code would help but in any case, I've got an `init` method just to initialize the JTable.

```
private void initTable(Object rowData[][]) {

documents = rowData;
dataModel = new DataModel(rowData, COLUMNS);
scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.setBounds(13, 188, 300, 148);
contentPane.add(scrollPane);

table = new JTable(dataModel) {
    @Override
    public void changeSelection(int rowIndex, int columnIndex, boolean toggle, boolean extend) {
        super.changeSelection(rowIndex, columnIndex, true, false);
    }

};
scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(30);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(260);
table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
ListSelectionModel cellSelectionModel = table.getSelectionModel();
cellSelectionModel.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

cellSelectionModel.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            int selectedRow = table.getSelectedRow();
            int selectedColumn = table.getSelectedColumn();
            if (selectedRow >= 0) {
                if (selectedColumn == 0) {
                    Boolean valorCol= (Boolean) documents[selectedRow][0];
                    if (valorCol== true) {
                        documents[selectedRow][0] = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        documents[selectedRow][0] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        table.clearSelection();
    }
});
}
```

_______EDITING_______

The way I remove the items are made of a List not the original array. After the procedure that moves the items from the JTable, I call the method above but this time the list is empty. Here it goes the "missing code"

After moving all the items...

```
Object[][] documentsMoved = buildTableDataFromList(myVO.getDocuments());
initTable(documentsMoved );

private Object[][] buildTableDataFromList(List<MyVO> list) {

    Object[][] retorno = new Object[list.size()][COLUMNS.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        MyVO vo = lista.get(i);
        retorno[i][CHECK_COL] = Boolean.TRUE;
        retorno[i][DOC_COL] = vo.getFileName();
    }
    return retorno;
}
```

Comment: `"I don't know if some code would help but in any case, I've got a init method just to init the JTable...."` -- yes code would definitely help, but I don't see the problem and can't guess the solution based on what you've posted. You will want to first **isolate** the source of the problem before coming here, else it may be impossible to help you. Your best bet is to try to create and post a [mcve], a minimal program that we can compile and run and that reproduces your problem for us. This would be code posted here and not in a link. Please read the [mcve] link for more on this.

Comment: `"It should not happen as I remove the itens from the array that keeps the JTable values"` -- this sounds a bit funky. You shouldn't mess with an array used to make your JTable's model but rather should change the table's model itself.

Comment: I was trying to write it here but I found it was better to edit the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are changing the `dataVector` of the `DataModel` directly. This is not the way you should be doing things. What you should do is change cell values through the interface of `DataModel` (using model indexes) or through the `JTable` interface (using view indexes).

So my advice would be to change your program to do what I just told. However if you insist on working the way you are you can signal the `DataModel` about changes in its underlying `dataVector`, if your `DataModel` extends `DefaultTableModel` which I assume it does or implements the `AbstractTableModel` interface. Call `documents.fireTableDataChanged();` after your changes to the whole model, or more granular when changing cells using `documents.fireTableCellUpdated(rowModelId,colModelId);`.

---

Another mistake you are making is mixing up view indexes and model indexes. These can be different if rows are sorted and/or columns moved around in your table. Before indexing the model with indexes returned from the view, you should be converting these view indexes with `JTable.convertRowIndexToModel` and `JTable.convertColumnIndexToModel`.

---

Applying this to your selectionListener:

> What you should be doing:

```
cellSelectionModel.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            int selectedRow = table.getSelectedRow();
            int selectedColumn = table.getSelectedColumn();
            if (selectedRow >= 0) {
                if (table.convertColumnIndexToModel(selectedColumn) == 0) {
                    Boolean valorCol = (Boolean) table.getValueAt(selectedRow,selectedColumn);
                    if (valorCol == true) {
                        table.setValueAt(Boolean.FALSE,selectedRow,selectedColumn);
                    }
                    else {
                        table.setValueAt(Boolean.TRUE,selectedRow,selectedColumn);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        table.clearSelection();
    }
});
```

---

> If you insist on working the way you are:

```
cellSelectionModel.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            int selectedRow = table.getSelectedRow();
            int selectedColumn = table.getSelectedColumn();
            if (selectedRow >= 0) {
                int rowModelId = table.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRow);
                int colModelId = table.convertColumnIndexToModel(selectedColumn);
                if (colModelId == 0) {
                    Boolean valorCol= (Boolean) documents[rowModelId][0];
                    if (valorCol== true) {
                        documents[rowModelId][0] = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        documents[rowModelId][0] = true;
                    }
                    dataModel.fireTableCellUpdated(rowModelId,0);
                }
            }
        }
        table.clearSelection();
    }
});
```

Alas I think with your understanding of swing and JTable, there are likely more problems in your code.

Comment: Nice bit of sleuthing here!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks =)